# jquery select multiple="multiple" with custom attributes when checkbox is checked one by one

Tags: jquery, checkbox, match, multi-select

my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/terveg/MbHVB/4/
my HTML code is:

```
MULTIPLE CHECKBOXES:
<div class="cck-fl">
    <input type="checkbox" id="user_chosen_groups0" name="user_chosen_groups[]" value="10" checked="checked" class="checkbox validate[require[required_user_chosen_groups]]" size="1" data="49" groups="lovers">
    <label for="user_chosen_groups0">group one</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="user_chosen_groups1" name="user_chosen_groups[]" value="11" class="checkbox validate[require[required_user_chosen_groups]]" size="1" data="48" groups="breeders">
    <label for="user_chosen_groups1">group two</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="user_chosen_groups2" name="user_chosen_groups[]" value="12" class="checkbox validate[require[required_user_chosen_groups]]" size="1" data="58" groups="shopers">
    <label for="user_chosen_groups2">group three</label>
</div>
<br />
<br/>
MULTIPLE SELECT:
<div id="cck1r_form_dash" class="cck_form cck_form_select_multiple">
    <select id="#dash" name="dash[]" class="inputbox select" size="10" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="49">group 1 match checkbox-value 10 + value 49</option>
        <option value="48">group 2 match checkbox-value 11 + value 48</option>
        <option value="58">group 3 match checkbox-value 12 + value 58</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to match multi checkboxes with multi select input.
When i check "group one" , "group 1 match checkbox-value 10 + value 49" must be selected
and loop for all options.. Logically, IF checbox is unchecked, related select option also must me "unselected". Also I have one option checked by default in my checkbox field, so related option in select also should be checked when page is loaded.
By the way, i have also custom attributes data="" for my checkbox...maybe is idea to use this?

I tried ~5 different solutions found here, but no one works. Please help me

Comment: Would you please *not* edit your question to make it harder to read? As much as you may find it intrusive of me to edit your question (to clearly show the code), I really am trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, but I don't understand why you need to do this?

```
var $selectOptions = $('#dash option');

$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {

    var $checkbox = $(this),
        checked = $checkbox.prop('checked');

    $selectOptions.filter(function () {
      var $option = $(this);
      return $option.val() === $checkbox.attr('data');
    }).prop('selected', checked);

}).trigger('change');
```

Here is a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MbHVB/8/